# Error in plot.zoo() : "attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'"

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I was replicating codes from DataCamp on my laptop:

```
 library(xts) 
 plot.zoo(flights_xts, plot.type = "multiple", ylab = labels)
 plot.zoo(flights_xts, plot.type = "single", lty = lty)
 legend("right", lty = lty, legend = labels)
```

and was getting the following errors while executing the above three lines of code:

```
Error in rep(ylab, length.out = ngraph) : 
attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'

Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : 
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is fixed when quotes (".") are used in function parameters:

```
plot.zoo(flights_xts, plot.type = "multiple", ylab = "labels")
plot.zoo(flights_xts, plot.type = "single", lty = "lty")
legend("right", lty = "lty", legend = "labels")
```

It's still interesting though that in on-line `DataCamp.com` environment these quotes were not required. Any comments about that?

Comment: The DataCamp environment could contain objects, `lty <- "lty"` and `labels <- "labels"`. But I can only guess, unless you reference a specific course exercise.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like datacamp.com objects lty and labels are predefined for this task.
For me works:

```
lty <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
labels <- c("Total", "Delay", "Cancel", "Divert")
```